# Difference between casting to (char*) and *(char**) in C (implementing malloc)

Tags: c, pointers, malloc

I came across some code that used both of these, seemingly interchangeably.

I'll give an example problem that I'm confused about:

Let's say I have some data in a doubly linked list, and I want to change certain characters/addresses in a block. So we have:

```
void* ptr; //points to beginning of block
void* prevPtr; //prev item in LL
void* nextPtr; //next item in LL
*((char *)ptr) = prevPtr;
*(*(char **)(ptr) + sizeof(char*)) = nextPtr;
```

In this example, what is the difference between the bottom two lines (other than obviously moving to the `nextPtr`'s location in memory)?

Answer (score 3):

`*((char *)ptr) = prevPtr;` is the same as:

```
char *temp = ptr;
*temp = prevPtr;
```

This is ill-formed because you are trying to assign a pointer to a character.

`*(*(char **)(ptr) + sizeof(char*)) = nextPtr;` is the same as:

```
char **t1 = ptr;
char *t2 = *t1;
t2[4] = nextPtr;    // assuming 4-byte pointers
```

This is also ill-formed as it assigns a pointer to a character.

You should get compiler messages about this error in both cases (don't be misled by gcc which tends to say "warning" for incompatible type conversions even though the code is actually an error).

---

`void *` is a generic pointer type. It's used for where you have an interface that is used to transport various pointer types. However, you are only allowed to convert a `void *` back to the pointer type that it came from.  Any other pointer conversion is not guaranteed to work, and it's especially likely to not do what was intended if you convert to a pointer type with a different number of `*`s.

To help decide what to do in your code, you'll have to go back and see how `ptr` was assigned in the first place.

Comment: My guess about why GCC generates warnings rather than errors is because of legacy code that uses such currently-incompatible-but-perhaps-once-acceptable assignments (and in some cases such assignments may be valid if the values are actually within the right range, but assigning a memory address to a character probably isn't very valid except on machines with either tiny amounts of memory or multibyte `char`s, and either way an explicit cast would probably be most appropriate for modern standards).

Comment: @JAB, even if you accept a castless assignment of a pointer value to a an lvalue of type `char` -- which isn't so unreasonable, since pointers can be converted to integer types -- the result of the given code would still be wrong on account of the fact that `char` is unlikely to be wide enough to represent the converted pointer value.  I see no way that the result could be the actual intention of the code's author.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Indeed, hence the latter part of my parenthetical statement. For M.M: "you are only allowed to convert a void * back to the pointer type that it came from" What happens if the original type was `void*`, such as for the return value of `malloc()`?

Comment: @JohnBollinger I think he's saying that , even though the conversion in this case is bogus, there are other cases where illegal conversions "worked" in legacy code, and the compiler doesn't bother to try and distinguish various degrees of illegality.  For example legacy code contains stuff like `int q; char *p = &q;` , where the coder meant `char *p = (char *)&q`, the compiler gives this warning and acts accordingly.

Comment: @M.M: the C standard says that a pointer to `void` may be converted to or from any object type. In general, you can't necessarily use such a pointer for very much except by converting it back to the original pointer type, but the standard does also say that `malloc()` and friends return a `void` pointer that can be assigned to a pointer of any object type and used to access such an object (or array of such objects).  So in that instance anyway, you're allowed to use the converted `void` pointer without any problems of undefined, unspecified, or indeterminate behavior.

Comment: @MichaelBurr Oh cool. Sanity is restored :) In general I guess it's intended that `(void *)p == (void *)(T *)p` always holds (if `p` is correctly aligned for `T`), although the standard doesn't explicitly say so

Answer (score 1):

In the first one, `ptr` is cast to a pointer to `char` and then `prevPtr`, not the value `prevPtr` points to but the address it stores, is assigned to the character-typed memory location `ptr` currently points to. In the second, `ptr` is cast to a pointer to a pointer to `char` and then dereferenced before adding the offset, which results in the value of `nextPtr` (not the value it points to) being written to one pointer-size offset after the location pointed to by `ptr`, which in your example should still be a character. In other words, your example code doesn't make sense, but hopefully my elaboration helped your understanding.

Comment: So to clarify, the value of `ptr` is some 8-byte memory address. I'm writing in a memory address at location `ptr`, and then writing in a memory address at location of `ptr + sizeof(char*)`.

Comment: @kzs in that case, `ptr` should always be interpreted as a pointer to an 8-byte memory address, not as a pointer to `char`.

Comment: It is important to recognize that in each case a *`char`* at the designated address is updated with the pointer value.  That assignment almost certainly overflows (without modifying any other than the one byte pointed to).  In neither case is the result likely to be what was intended.

Comment: @JohnBollinger That was what I was trying to imply, but I guess I should have been more explicit.

Comment: Aha! So really what I should do is cast to `(void**)` and derefence that in order to have the location be interpreted correctly?

Comment: @kzs what you have presented does not make clear what the intended behavior may be.  It is therefore impossible to say what code would express it correctly.  It is safe to say, however, that simply changing `char` to `void` in the given expressions does not yield correct code.

Comment: @kzs Pretty much, at least for the case of having `ptr` be interpreted correctly. But you also need to keep in mind that pointer arithmetic is based off of the size of the pointed-to type of the pointer being offset, not bare bytes. `((char*)ptr)++` will offset `ptr` by a different amount than `((int*)ptr)++`. I'm assuming `prevPtr` and `nextPtr` point to valid memory as well and that `(void*)(*prevPtr) + 1` is also a valid, allocated memory location.

Comment: `((char *)ptr)++` is ill-formed; `++` can only be applied to an lvalue

Comment: @M.M To my knowledge, the result of a reinterpreting cast operation is an lvalue if the original value was not a temporary. That might be C++-only, though, it's been a while since I fiddled with pointer casting in C.

Comment: That's only when casting to a reference type, in C++ .  In Standard C all casts give rvalues. (even casting to the same type).    Some compilers have implemented extensions in the past where `(T)x` is treated as `*(T *)&x`.

Comment: @M.M So just expressing it as `((char*)ptr + 1) != ((int*)ptr + 1)` would be better, then.